# Screen Size in Game template iOS9

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, ios9

I am trying to understand how to make my screen look the same in all iOS devices when building with Game Template.  I totally get using constraints when building in Single View Application Template but it seems game template doesn't use this.

```
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Background")
    background.posByCanvas(0.5, y: 0.5)
    background.xScale = 0.38
    background.yScale = 0.38
    background.zPosition = -1
    addChild(background)
```

I have a func posByCanvas that calculates the screen size and scales depending on the device but some things will be cut out.  Is there a way that I don't know about that just handles this?  Like when you use constraints and put the image to the borders and you loose nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, you have to setup the management of GameScene dimensions yourself. This depends on interaction between the app, the view, and the scene inside the view. To do that, you should overload "- (void)didChangeSize:(CGSize)oldSize" in your GameScene. You can find an example in Objective-c source that implements this as part of this [blog post](http://www.modejong.com/blog/post20_spritekit_repeat_shader), but you will of course need to adapt that to Swift syntax.